# Where is a good example of cocos2d version 2 code for a game?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I can't seem to find any examples of cocos2d version two code.  There are plenty of examples of earlier versions.  Anyone have an idea where I can find an example of cocos2d v2 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a Cocos2d 2.X tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10862/how-to-create-cool-effects-with-custom-shaders-in-opengl-es-2-0-and-cocos2d-2-x). The difference between Cocos2d 2.0 and the previous version of Cocos2d is only in Cocos2d 2.0 uses OpenGL 2.0

Comment: Didn't they change some of the classes and methods that you need to use, in general? This tutorial seems to only cover shading

Comment: For API changes there's the API reference: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

All 15 Kobold2D 2.0 projects have been ported to use cocos2d 2.0 and my Line-Drawing Kit also uses cocos2d 2.0. And Ray Wenderlich also wrote tutorials, so have many others and there are many open source cocos2d 2.0 projects around.

Check: http://www.kobold2d.com and http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/line-drawing-game-starterkit/ and http://www.raywenderlich.com/ and http://bit.ly/ONHyF4